# Get value of a parameter of an annotation in Java

Tags: java, reflection, aspectj

So I've got a code:

```
@Path("/foo")
public class Hello {

@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String getHtml(@Context Request request, @Context HttpServletRequest requestss){
  ...
}
```

I am using AspectJ to catch all calls to `getHtml` method. I would like to get parameters passed to `@Produces` and to `@Path` in my advice, i.e. `"/foo"` and `"text/html"` in this case. How can I do it using reflection ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

To get value of the `@Path` parameter:

```
String path = Hello.class.getAnnotation(Path.class).value();
```

Similarly, Once you have hold of `Method` `getHtml`

```
Method m = Hello.class.getMethod("getHtml", ..);
String mime = m.getAnnotation(Produces.class).value;
```

Comment: Ok so the first example is ok but there is `.value()` not `.value`. The second one does not work since Annotation class does not have a `value()` method.

Comment: the second one works but as @Vash showed:
        MethodSignature ms = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        Method m  = ms.getMethod();
        Produces pro = m.getAnnotation(Produces.class);

Comment: how can i get @Annotation(param1="One", param2="THIS") ?

Comment: @NinjaCoding Lets say you used annotation is on a method, once you hold the method object, you can use method.getAnnotation(Annotation.class).param1() to get the param1 value. 
Here you have named your annotation interface as Annotation.

Answer (score 6):

The annotation is based on interface logic. You need to call the valid member of it to retrieve the value.

Definition

```
public @interface Produces {
 String type();
}
```

Read example

```
for (Method m: SomeClass.class.getMethods() {
   Produces produce = m.getAnnotation(Produces.class);
   if (produce != null)
       System.out.println(produce.type());
}
```

Yes. You must use reflection to access to method definition. You can use [Class#MgetMethods()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods%28%29) to get the definition of method

For object you call `obj.getClass()` to get the class definition.