# Spring - is it possible to get all packages, registered with @ComponentScan?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to get list of all packages, registered with @ComponentScan?
I need to know, what (root?) packages have been registered in my Spring Boot application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution - [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime)

Use `org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider`

API

> A component provider that scans the classpath from a base package. It
>   then applies exclude and include filters to the resulting classes to
>   find candidates.

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner =
new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(<DO_YOU_WANT_TO_USE_DEFAULT_FILTER>);

scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(<TYPE_YOUR_ANNOTATION_HERE>.class));

for (BeanDefinition bd : scanner.findCandidateComponents(<TYPE_YOUR_BASE_PACKAGE_HERE>))
    System.out.println(bd.getBeanClassName());
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe long shot, but each @ComponentScan should be used with @Configuration (which is just another kind of spring bean). So you can enumerate all beans from application context and check via [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192552/get-value-of-a-parameter-of-an-annotation-in-java) which of them have @ComponentScan and get its value.