# Spring-Boot, Get all annotation values used by a method level bean project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm working on a Spring-Boot written with Kotlin project that uses a custom method level annotation `foo` that has a String property called `biz` throughout the project.

`@Foo(biz = "buzz")`

Is there a way with Spring-Boot or Kotlin to get a list of all the values used in the `biz` property of `foo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is function on `ListableBeanFactory`, which can retrieve all beans with given annotation and return map with beans - key is bean name and value bean instance. Kotlin example:

````
@Configuration
class AnnotatedBeansCounterConfig(
    context: AbstractApplicationContext
) {
    init {
        context.getBeansWithAnnotation(Foo::class.java).forEach { beanName, bean ->
            val annotation = bean::class.findAnnotation<Foo>()
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the spring beans from the context. Follow this tutorial:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-show-all-beans

Then you can use reflection to get the annotation arguments for each bean. There's an example here:

[Get value of a parameter of an annotation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192552/get-value-of-a-parameter-of-an-annotation-in-java)